# Ionic2/angular2 correct way of consuming service

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am learning to build Ionic-2 app, I have a few components which consume services that make an http call and fetch some data, which in turn will be set in component and will finally be displayed in template. I overall understood the flow but I am making some logical mistake while coding it.

**My example component:**

```
export class FarmList {

  items: Object;

  constructor(private testService: TestService, public nav: NavController){}

  getData(): any {

    this.items = this.testService.fetchData()

  }

  nextView(){

    this.nav.push(Farm)

  }

  showDetails(id: Number){

    this.nav.push(Farm, {
      param1: id
    })

  }
}
```

**My corresponding service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService{

    loading: boolean;
    data: Object;

    constructor(private http: Http){

        let myUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

        this.loading = true;
        this.http.request(myUrl)
          .subscribe(
            (res: Response) => {

            this.loading=false;
            this.data=res.json();

          });

    }

    public fetchData(){

        return this.data;

      }
}
```

**Screenshot of the app:**
[image]

So the problem here is:

- Unless I click ***Fetch*** button (which calls getData() function in the component) it will not load the data, somehow in the constuctor of the component the data must be set and not when I call `getData()` function. I tried writing `this.items = this.testService.fetchData()` this line in the constructor but it doesn't work.
- This problem further becomes worse when in another component and service I have to append `navparam` sent from this *FarmList* component: `let myUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.id ;` I try to append *this.id* which is set to  received navparam in it's constructor and I get *undefined*

  constructor (private nextService: NextService, navParams: NavParams){
          this.id = navParams.get("param1");
   }

I am simply trying to have a list on one page and then clicking on one of the list items will open new page with it's some more details. I am hitting this publically available API: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/ and then appending some number to it to get only one object.

**What is the correct way to do it?**

***UPDATE:*** I could solve the second problem by simply getting navParams in service constuctor and appending it to the url as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class NextService{

    loading: boolean;
    data: Object;
    id: Number;

    constructor(private http: Http, navParams: NavParams){

    this.id = navParams.get("param1");
    console.log("Second service fetching param: " + this.id)

        let myUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.id ;
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ngOninit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)?

Comment: No I didn't know about it. Any directions on how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ngOnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) might be what you are looking for:

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';
...
export class FarmList implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData()
    }
}
```

Read more at [angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

**EDIT:**

Due to your comments I took another look at what your calls are doing. In the component you are setting the data to whatever is returned from the fetchData function which is only returning what data is set to in the service. Which at the time that ngOnInit is called is just an empty object and then a few milliseconds later service.data gets changed to whatever is returned from your http async call.

The better practice would be to follow [Angular's Http getting started tutuorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). In essence I think you would end up with something more like this:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService{
        private myUrl: string = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
// loading: boolean; 
//move any logic that has to do with UI to the component... 
//this is more of a suggestion and has to do with MV* best practices

    constructor(private http: Http){
// I think it was in John Papa's Pluralsight video on angular 2 that said
// try to do as little as possible inside of the constructor
    }    

    public fetchData(){
//the key here is to return a promise (or observable) so that the 
//component can handle it when it gets resolved
        return this.http.get(myUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data)
      }
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';
...
export class FarmList implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOninit(){
        this.getData()
    }
    getData(){
        this.testService.fetchData().then(data => this.items = data)
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to implement Oninit it gives me compilation error saying: FarmList incorrectly implements interface 'Oninit'. Property ngOninit is missingin type FarmList. What does it mean? I did exactly the same as you mentioned and referred to docs.

Comment: Ok this was resolved: instead of ngOninit() it had to be ngOnInit(), it was a typo. However the list did not load automatically, I still had to click the button to call getData()

Comment: In that case you have some async issues. I will edit the answer in a moment

Comment: It looks promising, however I still didn't have luck!  First line in service was giving me compilation error, so I changed it to: myUrl:'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'; and in fetchData(): return this.http.get(this.myUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json().data). I did how you suggested in component and I get GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found) & EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object] errors. Response {_body: "Cannot GET /null↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers…} ;

Comment: ha ha "looks promising" when we're talking about promises... Sorry change your myUrl declaration to be private myUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

when you omit the http:// it decides to consider that you are loading a resource from your base url

you were getting parsing errors because let should be used within a function of a class to declare variables, and you were getting "null" as the url because of typescript... 

I have updated the answer for my own typos

Comment: Unfortunately I still get 'undefined'. On console.log(this.items) when called at second lines of ngOnInit() and getData(). I guess the service is now returning the correct data as I can see in the network. However assigning it seems like an issue :(

Comment: I figured out the error: In service it should be: .then(response => response.json()) -- .data I had to remove! Thank you so much. This answer is going to be helpful in all my future http requests!